# Autolayout: UITextFields with equal width in different UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm dealing with a problem with Auto-Layout (which sometimes I hate).

I have three static `UITableViewCell`s with a `UILabel` and `UITextField` inside each one. There is a **Horizontal Space constraint** between them set to 8 points in the first cell.

What I want is that the width of the `UITextField`s in the other cells match the width of the first one. I tried to use the **Equal Width Constraint**, but when I Ctrl+click one `UITextField` and release over the first, there is no constraint contextual menu, I get this instead.

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish what I want?

Also, I tried to use a **Proportional Width constraint** relative to the cell superview and, despite it works fine, on iPhone 6 and 6+ I get a extremely wide gap between the label and the text field.

Thanks.

**SOLUTION:** As many have said in comments and answers, is not possible to set a constraint between views in different superviews, so what I did was to create a single view to hold all the labels and textfields. Simple as that. Thanks to all for helping.

Comment: AFAIK you cant have equal width constraints for child views which has different parents. that is why you cant see the option when you Ctrl+click

Comment: I see. Well I'll try a different approach. Thanks.

Comment: i can see all your cells are having same child. So i would suggest go with dynamic table view cell with Label and text field and set the width of the text field based on the label width. yes it is a pain in the ass but UX is more important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you trying saying that one cell that has one textfield is equal to another cell with another textfield and you can't do that.
You only could say that both textfield has the same size if they are in the same view.

If you really need that you could create IBOutlet to that constraint and at your code say that another constraint has de same width, but of course, you will need handle with other thinks like update constraints after set size.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your cells are all the same. I would configure the layout in the subclass of the cell in code and only use the storyboard to tell which controller to call when a cell is selected.